# App failed due to RTK Query's auto-generated hooks import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I am trying to understand RTK Query by building a to-do app so that I can replace thunk APi with it in my React project, but this problem hinders me from doing so:

[image]

### RTK Query service:

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",
  tagTypes: ["Todos"],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:3500/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query({
      query: () => "todos",
      providesTags: ["Todos"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetTodosQuery } = apiSlice;
```

#### store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { apiSlice } from "./services/api";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

#### TodoList.js component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useGetTodosQuery } from "../services/api";
import { Todo } from "./Todo";

export const TodoList = () => {
  const { data: todos, isLoading } = useGetTodosQuery();
  //   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      {todos?.map((todo) => (
        <Todo title={todo.title} key={todo.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Todo.jsx component:

```
export const Todo = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="todo">
      <p>{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Based on the code stacktrace it seems that React is null. Have you ensured that all project dependencies have been correctly installed? Open a terminal in the root project directory (*where the package.json file is located*) and run `npm install` to ensure the project dependencies are installed.

Comment: @DrewReese I have done that but the problem persists. Thanks

Comment: Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese While I was setting up sandbox for the project, I got an error saying indicating that @reduxjs/toolkit was not install. So I went ahead to install it, and to my biggest surprise, the error disappears. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why node was just beating around the bush instead of specifying the actual problem.

Comment: It's always something silly. Glad it's working for you now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause of the error was absence of @reduxjs/toolkit package. Installing the package cleared the error.

`npm install @reduxjs/toolkit`

The project is available on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/belloshehu/RTK-qeury-todo/draft/silly-hooks?workspaceId=33a9762e-5a73-4356-8718-631f855fd324) and [gitHub](https://github.com/belloshehu/RTK-qeury-todo)